# Is it possible to precisely change offset of a view using OnDrag & Ondrop provided by Swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, offset

I know, we can achieve this using DragGesture() as DragGesture() provides drag startLocation, translation and we can precisely calculate offset of dragged view but I am trying to achieve similar functionality using OnDrag & Ondrop.

But as far as I have found, OnDrag & Ondrop does not provide drag StartLocation or anything to precisely calculate offset change of dragged view. I can get the start location as tap gesture point using onTapGesture(available after iOS 16.0) or DragGesture(minimumDistance:0). But the problem is accessing first touch/Tap point (DragStartLocation) and OnDrag & Ondrop does not occur simultaneously.

can anyone help me in this regard? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.